# NP-complete problems with optimal approximation in poly-time

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, np-hardness, approximation-algorithms

I'm looking for examples of hard optimization problems, for which we have an optimal approximation (not that this is not the same as $PTAS$, as we require a completely tight approximation, and not $1+\epsilon$-multiplicative approximation), in a sense defined as follows:

Formally, let $L\subseteq\Sigma^*\times \mathbb N$ be the decision version of some minimization (or maximization, flipping the definitions) problem, i.e. 
$$\forall n\leq m:(w,n)\in L\implies (w,m)\in L$$

Which examples of such known languages $L$ is $NP$-hard, but if we are allowed of a *minimal relaxation*, it is poly time solvable.

By *minimal relaxation* I mean that there exists a TM such that given an input $(w,n)$:

- The machine accepts if $(w,n+1)\in L$.
- The machine rejects if $(w,n-1)\not \in L$.
- The machine may act arbitrarily on other cases.

An example for such problem is the [Degree-constrained spanning tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree-constrained_spanning_tree), where the problem is finding an MST with minimal maximum vertex degree.

> **Which other languages are NP-hard but subject to optimal approximation in poly time?**

Comment: 3-coloring problem on planar graphs is $NP$-hard while every planar graph is 4-colorable in polynomial time (by the four color theorem).

Comment: I guess there is an issue of discretization that is tricky. For example, if we want to formalize Max-Cut in this framework, what is the meaning of $n+1$ and $n-1$?

Comment: @usul - since Max-Cut is a maximization problem you'll need to reverse the definitions: given an instance $<G,k>$, accept if there exists a cut with at least $k-1$ edges, reject if there is no cut with $k+1$ edges. Since Max-Cut is $APX$-hard, I don't think it is a good candidate here.

Comment: OK, I see. I was thinking that $k$ was a fraction of edges in the graph.

Comment: Maybe better term for optimal approximation or minimal relaxation is approximation with additive constant error.

Comment: @Saeed, can you explain how that's equivalent? I think the issue is that I still don't understand what the role of the constant $1$ is in the definition.

Comment: @usul I didn't understand what you don't understand. But you can search about additive constant error to understand what it is, assuming you know this, OP's question is about additive error 1 (replace constant with 1)

Comment: So for instance, if we flip the definition from minimization to maximization, then this class would contain the language $L = \{(w,k) : w$ is a graph on $n$ nodes with a maximum cut of at most $k n^2\}$. Similarly when we change to $\alpha k n^2$ for various values of the constant $\alpha$. But (under common assumptions) this class does not contain $L = (w,k): w$ a graph with a max cut of at most $k$. Is that right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One example is the **chromatic index** (edge-coloring number) of undirected graphs. By Vizing's theorem, the chromatic index either equals the max-degree $\Delta$ or equals $\Delta+1$.

- Vizing's proof gives a polynomial time (inductive) procedure for finding a coloring with $\Delta+1$ colors.
- Holyer has proved that deciding whether the chromatic index equals $\Delta$ is NP-complete.